# How to access .txt file via Community Site

Tags: community

We have a community site. We need to access (.txt) file via Site. Salesforce has an option to do this using https://community_URL/robots.txt. But we do not want to use robots.txt name instead use custom name like https://community_URL/mycustomfile.txt.

Comment: Note that [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) is a metadata feature for indexing purposes. You can't arbitrarily expose a random txt file in the root folder of the community.

Comment: I understand the purpose of robots.txt file. We are also looking to index our .txt file for google to crawl . But customer wants to use custom name instead of robots.txt.

Comment: If you don't use robots.txt, it won't be parsed by google/yahoo/bing/etc. The name is literally baked into the protocol.